# Stream multiple Twitter timelines including protected

Tags: php, api, symfony, twitter, streaming

I'm creating a simple Twitter app where I want to stream the timeline of the logged in user, but I can't figure out the right way.

With hard coded parameters it works fine, but I don't know how should I pass the logged in user's (token, who they are following) to the stream processor (which is running separately, in terminal), which checks the right timeline and returns it.

I also would like to get the tweets of the protected people followed by the user, but Stream API doesn't support that.

I'm using the [Impensavel\Floodgate](https://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwii1ueI_KHHAhVEWhQKHfzJDh8&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpackagist.org%2Fpackages%2Fimpensavel%2Ffloodgate&ei=gGjKVaKWO8S0UfyTu_gB&usg=AFQjCNER7l48ySFnNUt3M-IqCLdUBwJNNA&sig2=Ks8AZI77VCdkipiiuScNcw&bvm=bv.99804247,d.d24) library, and, and my simple hard coded classes looks like this:

```
class Streaming extends Floodgate
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getParameters()
    {
        return [
            'follow' => 83408038
        ];
    }
}
```

This starts the actual requests, I just made a Symfony command out of it:

```
class StreamCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

 protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('stream:start');
    }
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface    $output)
  {
    $config = [
        'consumer_key' => '**',
        'consumer_secret' => '**',
        'token' => '**',
        'token_secret' => '**',
    ];

    $stream = Streaming::create($config);

    $stream->filter(function ($data) {
        if(isset($data->text)){
            echo $data->text . PHP_EOL;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

With what kind of logic could I achieve the streaming of each user's own timeline, including protected users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I managed to solve this problem with using ReactPHP to run the stream processes, and Ratchet to communicate with the client side.